# Serialize to json rails models with associated records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, to-json

Suppose I have Folder with `has_many` association to File.

I had a small action where I rendered json like this

```
render json: folder.to_json(include: :files)
```

I've tried to render a bit more complicated json response with following

```
render json: {status: 'ok', main_folder: folder}
```

but this obviously doesn't include associated records. How can I include them?

P.S. I would like not to use views in this application and not to override `to_json` method (as I want to render in another action complicated json with Folder records, but without associated Files) in models if it is possible.

**EDIT** I've managed to find a workaround for the problem, but it looks ugly

```
intermediate_obj = folder.attributes.merge(files: folder.files)
render json: {status: 'ok', main_folder: intermediate_obj}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

`render json: {status: 'ok', main_folder: folder.as_json(include: :files}`